# question about htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

what is htaccess file? how to create and write that? what is the advantage of using htaccess file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.htaccess files provide a way to `make configuration changes on a per-directory basis`. See the [official Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/htaccess.html) for .htaccess files.

Answer (score 2):

.htaccess allows you to override Apache's (and other servers') main configuration file for a particular directory (and all its subdirectories). To use .htaccess you simply create a new file and name it ".htaccess" (yes, the name is very unusual because it actually consist of only a very long file extension), upload it to you server (if you want to affect your entire site than put is in your root folder), and finally add some directives.

If you wand to see what sort of things you can configure with .htaccess check out this very accessible tutorial: [5 most useful applications of the .htaccess file](http://whiteecho.co.uk/5-most-useful-applications-htaccess-file).

For something more comprehensive visit [guide .htaccess](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess.shtml).

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This is majorly used for configuration on server the generally things involve in usage are following.
-(redirecting server to specific file)
Redirect permanent /index.html (new path)
For more you can refer to http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/htaccess.html#related

Comment: “While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.”